# Failed to query connected AWS S3 in Google BigQuery

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to get information from AWS S3 to Google BigQuery and I've set up permissions based on official documents and also finished connecting to roles. The region of AWS S3 is us-west-1, and I set the Data Location to aws-us-west-2 when I created the external connection in BigQuery.
AWS Role id is also well included in "arn:aws:iam::0000:role/My_role_name", and BigQuery Google identity is also in trust relationship.

bq_omni_read_only policy json

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52W3x.png)

trust relationship

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "accounts.google.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "accounts.google.com:sub": "my_BigQuery_Google_identity",
                    "accounts.google.com:aud": "my_BigQuery_Google_identity"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

When I ran the query with External connection on the BigQuery page of the Google Cloud console, I used the following code.

```
SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("my_connection_id", "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;");
```

However, the following error occurred.

```
Invalid table-valued function EXTERNAL_QUERY External database credentials not found for connection my_connection_id at [1:15]
```

Does this mean that I did something wrong when setting permissions on AWS? I waited about 12 hours after seeing the document that says it can be applied after a few hours if I modify the trust relationship, but the error is still occurring.

Or is my authority on Google Cloud a problem? I have the BigQuery admin rights, but is it not enough?

I've been using BigQuery for the first time and read the document for a few days, but I still don't understand it... please help.....

**I used a translator because I was not good at English.